# TypeError in Vue.js while using clickevent on button.

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, shopping-cart

I am trying to add products to my shoppingcart but I keep bumping to the uncaught TypeError, since I am new to front-end development this is a pain in the ass for me.

This is the error that is shown to me. 
[image]

If I go to the pointed javascriptfile I find this. The :4 throws on the product.quantity = 1;
This is part of the **Mutation.js**

```
export const addProductToCart = (state, product) => {
  product.quantity = 1;
  state.cart.push(product);
};
```

When I go to the **Action.js** I see this code. This is going to check the index of the clicked object and add this to the cart.

```
export const addProductToCart = ({ state, commit }, product) => {
 const exists = state.cart.find(exists => exists.Id === product.Id);

 if (exists) {
   commit("updateProductQuantity", product);
 }else {
   commit("addProductToCart", product);
 }
};
```

Now to my **ProductList.vue** In the template content I added this code to my button for adding the product to the cart.

```
<b-button variant="primary" @click="addProductToCart(product)">           
Add to cart</b-button>
```

For the same file here is the code of the whole script section.

```
<script>
export default {
 name: "product-list",
 props: {
   products: {
     type: Array,
     required: true,
   }
 },
 methods: {
   view(product) {
     this.$router.push (`/products/${product.slug}`);
    },
 addProductToCart(product) {
    this.$store.commit("addProductToCart", this.product);
    this.$toastr("success", "Product added to cart successfully.");
  },
 }
};
</script>
```

The **index.js** file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

import * as actions from "./actions";
import * as mutations from "./mutations";
import * as getters from "./getters";

const store = new Vuex.Store({
 strict: true,
 actions,
 mutations,
 getters,
 state: {
    cart: [],  
 }
});

store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
 localStorage.setItem("store", JSON.stringify(state));
});
export default store;
```

Im stuck on this for a day or 2 already trying multiple different other options. But I do not find any solution.

Is there anything I am missing here?
Is this code sufficient for finding a solution? Or do I need to search somewhere else.

Kind regards.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `product` ? In `addProductToCart()` function, `console.log(product)` for example

Comment: You're using `this.product` In the `ProductList.vue` method `addProductToCart`. Where is `this.product` though? There is no variable or computed property with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Bennett Dams in the comments; The problem lives here:

```
addProductToCart(product) {
    this.$store.commit("addProductToCart", this.product);
    this.$toastr("success", "Product added to cart successfully.");
},
```

As you can see, your method takes the `product` as a parameter, but then you are trying to send `this.product` to your vuex action (and `this.product` is indeed `undefined`). You should replace your code by:

```
addProductToCart(product) {
    this.$store.commit("addProductToCart", product);
    this.$toastr("success", "Product added to cart successfully.");
},
```

Comment: The error is gone, not working yet, but this issue is already fixed, thank you hammerbot and @Bennett Dams.
Stupid mistake!